# Si hago una inserción en sql desde php pero esta no inserta puedo hacer un die?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Ejemplo:

```
$row = mssql_query ('Insert into columna values('juan')');

if ($set=mssql_query($row) ==0)
   die ('No se inserto');
```

Comment: Tus dos últimas preguntas son muy parecidas y no se ajustan muy bien al formato del sitio. "¿Puedo hacer xyz?" no es una buena pregunta, primero prueba a hacerlo y si falla, pregunta sobre el fallo. Y si ya lo probaste y falló, entonces no preguntes si puedes hacerlo, directamente di "me falla al hacer esto, ¿por qué es?¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?"

Comment: hermano uso para algunas cosas grcias por estar atento recien estoy tratando de aprender php para ayudar a mis compañeros de clases tengo teamview y skype pero no se si las normas de aqui me permiten publicarlo Gracias.

Comment: No veo por qué haya que hacer un die. Ver esta respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/57382/29967

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta era más simple, la investigué y resultó ser:

```
$row = mssql_query ('Insert into columna values('juan')');

if($row==1)
{
   die ('No se inserto');  
}
else
{
eho "perfecto si inserto";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay un error en la sintaxis, por el uso de comillas simples/dobles:

```
$row = mssql_query ("Insert into columna values('juan')");
```

---

Respondiendo a la pregunta y revisando la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-query.php), **SÍ**, es posible hacer un die:

> Devuelve un recurso de resultado MS SQL en caso de éxito, TRUE si no se devolvieron registros, o FALSE en caso de error.

Teniendo en cuenta que devuelve FALSE en caso de error, es posible hacer esto:

```
if (!mssql_query ("Insert into columna values('juan')")) {
    die("No se insertó);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de esta forma SELECT:

```
<?php
// asumimos que $ip ya existe con un valor real

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE ip='$ip'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
  // ya existe una fila con el $ip especificado
}
else
{
  // NO existe, entonces... INSERT
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Miquel Coll, como hiciste fondo color gris y fuente color rojo