# ¿Cómo hacer un die(); en PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo este código de conexión con base de datos:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'cssnewlogin';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

//We do the connection:
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, FALSE);
```

Y ejecuto un simple INSERT:

```
$sthinsert = $pdo->prepare(

    "INSERT INTO lithuania_customers_2016

    (user_id, customer_db_id, campaign_id)

    VALUES (:user_id, :customer_db_id, :campaign_id)"

    );

    $sthinsert->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sthinsert->bindValue(':customer_db_id', $customer_db_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sthinsert->bindValue(':campaign_id', $campaign_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$sthinsert->execute();
```

¿En qué momento tengo que hacer un `die();` para que después de ejecutar código deseado no hayan otros comportamiento inesperados?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de comportamientos inesperados?
Cuando finalices puedes cerrar la conexión sin más poniendo a NULL la variable $pdo, si quieres hacer un die() sin más, tal cual finalizas la insert, aunque podrías comprobar primero que funciono.

Comment: Había encontrado en la documentación que esos comportamiento existen aunque nunca los experimenté por mi mismo. ¿Cómo poner $pdo a NULL?

Comment: _¿En qué momento tengo que hacer un die(); para que después de ejecutar código deseado no hayan otros comportamiento inesperados?_ En ningún momento. No tiene por qué haber comportamientos inesperados, a no ser que después del insert tú intentes hacer otra cosa. Ni siquiera la conexión PDO es necesario cerrarla, aunque puedes hacerlo si lo deseas. Si no la cierras PHP la cierra cuando termina el script. Ver esta respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50097/29967

Comment: @A.Cedano podrías poner tu comentario como respuesta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿En qué momento tengo que hacer un die(); para que después de ejecutar
>   código deseado no hayan otros comportamiento inesperados?

**En este caso** la respuesta es **en ningún momento**.

No tiene por qué haber comportamientos inesperados, a no ser que después del `INSERT` tú intentes hacer otra cosa.

Ni siquiera la conexión PDO es necesario cerrarla, aunque puedes hacerlo si lo deseas. Si no la cierras PHP la cierra cuando termina el script.

Del [manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php):

> Una vez realizada con éxito una conexión a la base de datos, será
>   devuelta una instancia de la clase PDO al script. La conexión
>   permanecerá activa durante el tiempo de vida del objeto PDO. Para
>   cerrar la conexión, es necesario destruir el objeto asegurándose de
>   que todas las referencias a él existentes sean eliminadas; esto se
>   puede hacer asignando NULL a la variable que contiene el objeto. Si no
>   se realiza explícitamente, PHP cerrará automáticamente la conexión
>   cuando el script finalice.
>
> Nota: Si aún existen otras referencias a esta instancia de PDO (tales
>   como desde una instancia de PDOStatement, o desde otras variables que
>   hacen referencia a la misma instancia de PDO), estas también han de
>   eliminarse (por ejemplo, asignando NULL a la variable que hace
>   referencia al PDOStatement).

Más detalles en esta respuesta: [¿Es necesario cerrar una conexión con PDO luego de ejecutar una sentencia?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50097/29967)

No tienes que ir llenando todo de `dies()`por todas partes, sino ir contronlando tu código. Si por ejemplo el `INSERT` está dentro de un bucle o dentro de una condición `if then else` controlar que la evaluación se haga correctamente y que el código pase por donde quieres que pase, sin que se quede en un bucle infinito o algo así.

**EDIT:**

Por lo que sí debes preocuparte es de verificar que  tu `execute` tuvo éxito o no, haciendo algo como esto:

```
$resultado = $sthinsert->execute();
if ($resultado) {...}
```

Si tuvo éxito `$resultado` será verdadero (TRUE) y puedes poner dentro del if algún mensaje indicándolo o pasar a otra acción, si no tuvo éxito puedes agregar un else para indicarlo.

Comment: Es más: cualquier `die()` o `exit()` es una mala práctica en ambiente productivo. Lo correcto es manejar una excepción y enviar una respuesta con su respectivo header, aunque ese header sea 500 al menos dará lugar a un stack trace. Esa vieja práctica de hacer `$db = mysql_connect() or die()` es pésima.

Comment: @amenadiel Correcto. Además, si llamas el INSERT desde otro sitio, con el `die ()` matas la continuación... bueno, eso creo. En realidad nunca he usado el tal `die()`. Me gustaría que los más entendidos en PHP dijesen si en realidad sirve para algo y en cuáles casos :)

Comment: Es una práctica legacy de cuando PHP no tenía excepciones, y se siguió usando asiduamente hasta que PHP empezó a soportar los  custom error handlers y custom exception handlers. Un die() en PDO puede por ejemplo dejar conexiones zombie o transacciones abiertas esperando un commit que nunca llegará

Answer (score 4):

Respuesta corta: **nunca**. Un die() o exit() no es la manera natural de terminar el flujo de un script. Lo correcto sería usar una excepción, ya sea al crear la conexión o al ejecutar el statement. Un ejemplo mínimo sería:

```
try {
  $sthinsert->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Respuesta larga:**

Había una vez, en una galaxia muy lejana, la práctica de "intentar conectarse o morir".

```
$conn = mysql_connect( 'host.name', 'user', 'password') or die("Error: " . mysql_errno() . " " . mysql_error());
```

¿Qué significa esto? Que un error en `mysql_connect` se omite silenciosamente. Recibe un null o un booleano FALSE y que uno tiene que preguntar explícitamente cuál fue el último error.

Con el advenimiento del Test Driven Development quedó en evidencia que esa es una mala práctica: es imposible de testear. Si el comportamiento esperado fuese:

> La aplicación debe informar de un error de conexión cuando la BBDD no esté disponible

Es imposible pasar ese test, porque al hacer `die` o `exit` matas también al test runner.

---

Aunque hacer tests esté muy fuera del alcance de esta pregunta, lo importante es que PDO está hecho para manejar excepciones. Está en su naturaleza de tal modo que no necesitas convertir errores en excepciones, ni pedir el último error. Es más: PDO implementa su propio tipo de Excepciones ([PDOException](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdoexception.php)) por si quieres atrapar distintas clases de excepciones en un scope superior.

¿Cómo aprovechar esto? Simplemente te preparas para una excepción.

En tu mismo ejemplo usas esa opción:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,// <-- excepciones
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
```

Luego en vez de simplemente hacer (como en tu ejemplo)

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Debieses hacer (para aprovechar las excepciones):

```
function conectarse() {

    try {
      $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
      return $pdo;
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
      print_r($e->getMessage());
      return null;
    }

}

$conn = conectarse();
if($conn === null) {
   echo 'No se puso realizar la conexión';
}
```

Lo bueno de las excepciones es que se propagan hacia arriba, así que también podrías hacer:

```
function conectarse() {
  ....
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
  return $pdo;
}

try {
    $conn = conectarse();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();    
}
```

Y así sucesivamente. Cualquier statement de PDO puede ser envuelto en un try/catch, o de lo contrario una excepción se propagará hasta el try/catch que encuentre en un scope superior.

Volviendo al caso de Test Driven Development, en vez de matar el script junto al test runner, tú sí puedes decir:

> El programa debe arrojar una excepción xxx cuando no se pueda conectar

Una excepción es perfectamente testeable y te permite continuar el flujo de tu script modificando su comportamiento hasta entregar una respuesta al usuario.

Además, una excepción incluye los métodos [$e->getTrace()](http://php.net/manual/es/exception.gettrace.php) y [$e->getTraceAsString()](http://php.net/manual/es/exception.gettraceasstring.php) que te permiten saber exactamente dónde ocurrió la excepción, desde dónde se llamó a esa parte del código, y desde dónde se llamó a la parte desde donde se llamó (y así sucesivamente hasta creo que el décimo antecesor).

En una aplicación de mediana complejidad sería muy trabajoso darle a cada `die()` un mensaje que indicara claramente cuál fue el error y dónde se produjo. Por ejemplo, puede que 10 scripts distintos invoquen a la función que crea la conexión. Con un `die()` no es trivial saber cual de esos 10 es el que generó la falla.

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido bien, el `die();` lo debes poner después de la línea `$sthinsert->execute();`

Así después de la ejecución del `INSERT` no sigue ejecutando nada más.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Parece que funciona. Tambien debería poner un die(); después de "SELECT * FROM tabla ..." ?

Comment: Debería poner un die(); en todas las páginas en las que utilizo una conección? Por favor amplifica tú respuesta y daré mi pregunta por resuelta..

Comment: Irás llenando todo de `dies()`. ¿Acaso hay algo después del `$sthinsert->execute();`? Si no hay nada, ¿qué se va a ejecutar si no hay nada más? Si el execute está en un bucle o en una condición if sólo tienes que preocuparte de que estén bien construidos, si no está dentro de nada no tienes por qué poner `die()`. No trates a PHP como si fuera un programa tonto que no sabe lo que tiene que hacer. Ni siquiera la conexión PDO estás obligado a cerrarla, PHP la cierra cuando el script termina. Saludos.

Comment: Por las respuestas que se ven, ¡no hagas die() nunca!
Yo lo uso ocasionalmente cuando estoy trazando código, e igual que los pongo los quito. Creía que lo usaba en una clase que tengo por hay para re-direcciones después de un header(), pero no, ahora que lo miro es un exit(), que también es el demonio. Cerrar la conexión: $conn = NULL; Como hacer un die() si tu script no hace más es innecesario, PHP cierra todo automáticamente para ahorrar recursos, no es como otros lenguajes que aunque tienen recolector de basura, es una buena practica liberar recursos implícitamente.