# Se guarda en la db pero no se actualiza el DOM

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "data_estudiantes";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());    
}

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];

$sql = "insert into estudiantes (nombre, apellidos, cedula) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$cedula')";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);
$id = $conn->insert_id;
echo json_encode(array('id'=>$id, 'nombre' => $nombre, 'apellidos' => $apellidos, 'cedula' => $cedula));
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'addEstudent.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {nombre: nombre, apellidos:apellido, cedula:cedula},
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var fila = '<tr id="'+data['id']+'"><td>'+ data['nombre'] +'</td><td>'+ data['apellidos'] +'</td><td>'+data['cedula']+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger eliminarBtn" data-idest = "'+value['id']+'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button></td></tr>';
        $('tbody').append(fila);
        $('#contador').html($('tbody tr').length);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
 });
});
```

Comment: No se actualiza, o se actualiza de forma incorrecta? Algún error en la consola?

Comment: Cambiar `value['id']`  por `data['id']` que es lo que recibe.

Answer (score 1):

A primera vista se ve un error de variables *(a menos que sea algo que no está en el código de ejemplo)* pero el arreglo `value` no existe, tendría que acceder a `data['id']` que es lo recibe de respuesta. El código se morirá en esa línea *value is not defined* por lo tanto no hace el `append` correctamente.

> Además su código es muy inseguro, recomendación obligatoria es leer
>   sobre Inyección SQL con valores concatenados o leer la pregunta y respuestas de  [¿Cómo
>   Evitar ataques de Inyección SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 0):

Me permitiré señalar algunas cosas en tu código. Lo leeré línea por línea y te daré algunas recomendaciones:

1. `die` un [horror](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/57382/29967).

   Particularmente `die` no me gusta. Mucho menos si la petición Ajax está esperando un objeto JSON.

   Para evitar el horror de `die`en caso de error, guardaremos el mensaje en un array que será nuestra respuesta al servidor.
2. No estás verificando las variables del `$_POST`

   Uno es a veces *ingenuo* cuando programa y cree que todo va a salir como uno piensa, pero resulta que no siempre es así. Entonces, evalúa tus variables `$_POST`
3. El eterno problema de la [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967). Tu código es de esos que les encantan a los hacker para inyectar código malicioso en tu base de datos. Aplica consultas preparadas, que para eso existe la extensión MySQLi.
4. Cuando respondas JSON desde el servidor, indícalo en el header.
5. [jQuery recomienda usar `done`, `fail`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/98896/29967) y demás familiares para manejar peticiones Ajax. El tan repandido `success` aunque no lo creas, es obsoleto desde jQuery 3.

Ahora vamos a aplicar esos cinco parches a tu código:

### PHP

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "data_estudiantes";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    /*Parche 1*/
    $arrRespuesta=array("error"=>"Error de conexión: ".mysqli_connect_error()); 

}else{

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];

    /*Parche 2*/
    if ($nombre !== '' && $apellidos !== '' && $cedula !== '')
    {

        /*Parche 3*/
        $sql = "insert into estudiantes (nombre, apellidos, cedula) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);

       /*Evaluar si  la preparación tuvo  éxito*/
        if ($stmt) 
        {
             /*
               * Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
               * la letras "sss" indican el tipo de cada dato que se va a insertar
               * s: String, si es una cadena , i: Integer, si fuera un entero, etc
               * Ejecutar
            */
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $nombre,$apellidos,$cedula);
            $stmt->execute();
            $id = $conn->insert_id;         
            $arrResultado=array('id'=>$id, 'nombre' => $nombre, 'apellidos' => $apellidos, 'cedula' => $cedula);

        }else{

            $arrResultado=array("error"=>"Hubo un error con la consulta");

        }

    }else{

        $arrResultado=array("error"=>"Hay variables vacías en el POST");

    }       

}
    /*
        *Parche 4:
        *Si observas, hasta ahora no hemos impreso nada
        *hemos ido guardando todo en un arreglo
        *y ahora lo imprimimos, así aseguramos que siempre el servidor
        *responderá con un JSON que podremos evaluar del lado del cliente
    */
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($arrResultado);
?>
```

### jQuery / JS

Usaremos `done`, `fail` para actualizar el código. Ese será el Parche 5:

```
var request = $.ajax
    ({
        url: "addEstudent.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {nombre: nombre, apellidos:apellido, cedula:cedula},
        dataType: "json"
        });

    request.done(function( data ) 
    {
        console.log(data);

        /*
         *Verificamos que no hay error en la respuesta
         *para eso en PHP fuimos controlando el código
         *y creando un array con los datos o con mensajes de error
        */
        if (!data.error)
        {
            var fila = 
                        '<tr id="'+data.id+'">
                            <td>'+ data.nombre +'</td>
                            <td>'+ data.apellidos+'</td>
                            <td>'+data.cedula+'</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger eliminarBtn" data-idest = "'+data.id+'">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button></td>
                         </tr>';
            $('tbody').append(fila);
            $('#contador').html($('tbody tr').length);

        }else{

            /*
               *Aquí podremos acceder al mensaje de error
               *que viene en el JSON mediante data.error
               *si quieres, puedes imprimirlo en alguna parte del DOM
            */

            console.log(data.error);

        }

    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
    {
        alert( "La petición Ajax falló: " + textStatus );
    });
```

Comment: Excelente explicación @A. Cedano, muchas gracias si no es mucha molestia, deseo actualizar los datos con un boton similar al eleminar, pero al dar click se deben presentar los datos en los campos de texto, si no es mucha molestia y me das una mano con eso te agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Yo o cualquier otro te podría dar una mano con ese problema y con cualquier otro @V.Rocha, ahora bien, este sitio funciona por preguntas. No es bueno abordar otro asunto dentro de otra pregunta. Por varios motivos: se necesita una exposición más clara del contexto de ese otro problema (lo cual debería ser planteado en otra pregunta); estaríamos mezclando dos problemas; te perderás de los puntos de vista de otros usuarios en posibles respuestas; un problema que podría ser importante quedaría ofuscado, dentro de otro que es relacionado, pero que a su vez es diferente.

Comment: Ok mil gracias, lo voy a tomar en cuenta

Comment: @V.Rocha por favor consulta [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Si el problema planteado aquí ha sido resuelto sugiero que marques la respuesta que te ha conducido a encontrar dicha solución. Saludos.