# ¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, pdo

Me ha pasado varias veces que me encuentro generando una consulta, ya sea `SELECT`, `INSERT` o  `UPDATE` en `PHP`, el cual falla y rápidamente no logro saber porque!

#### Ejemplo 1:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (null, "Marcos")';
$resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
// ¿Por que $resultado es false?
```

#### Ejemplo 2:

```
$query = 'SELECT id, name FROM usuarios';
$resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
// ¿Por que $resultado es false?
```

¿Cual es la forma en PHP de obtener el motivo por el cual mi consulta fallo?

Comment: La idea de esta pregunta es documentar esto en un solo lugar. Cualquier sugerencia de como modificarla para que sea más inclusiva es bienvenida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)

### Usando consultas directas:

Para poder obtener el error que generó la última consulta podemos usar [`mysqli_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php)

**Ejemplo estilo orientado a objeto:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'mi_usuario', 'mi_contraseña', 'mi_bd');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error de Conexión (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (null, "Marcos")';
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($res === false) {
    echo "SQL Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

**Ejemplo estilo por procedimientos:**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_db");
if (!$conn) {
    die('Error de Conexión (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (null, "Marcos")';
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if ($res === false) {
    echo "SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

---

### Usando [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

Para poder obtener el error que generó la última sentencia invocada podemos usar [`mysqli_stmt_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.error.php)

**Ejemplo estilo orientado a objeto:**

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (null, ?)';
$stm = $mysqli->prepare($query);
if ($stm === false) {
    echo "SQL Error: " . $mysqli->error;
} else {

    $name = 'Marcos';
    $stm->bind_param("s", $name);
    $res = $stm->execute();
    if ($res === false) {
        echo "SQL Error: " . $stm->error;
    }
}
```

**Ejemplo estilo por procedimientos:**

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (null, ?)';
$stm = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if ($stm === false) {
    echo "SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
} else {

    $name = 'Marcos';
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stm, "s", $name);
    $res = mysqli_stmt_execute($stm);
    if ($res === false) {
        echo "SQL Error: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stm);
    }
}
```

---

## [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php)

#### Usando consultas directas

Para poder obtener el error asociado con la última operación podemos usar [`PDO::errorInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php)

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (null, "Marcos")';
$res = $conn->query($query);
if ($res === false) {
    echo "SQL Error: " . $conn->errorInfo()[2];
}
```

#### Usando sentencias preparadas

Para poder obtener el error asociado con la última operación del gestor de sentencia podemos usar [`PDOStatement::errorInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (null, :name)';
$stm = $conn->prepare($query);
if ($stm === false) {
    echo "SQL Error: " . $conn->errorInfo()[2];
} else {

    $res = $stm->execute(['anem' => 'Marcos']);
    if ($res === false) {
        echo "SQL Error: " . $stm->errorInfo()[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo evitaría el uso de `die` ([ver más detalles en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/57382/29967)). Es mejor controlar el flujo del código, asignando el mensaje de error a una variable de salida.

Comment: Otra cosa, dado que existe también un [método de obtención de error para las sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.error.php) quizá sea interesante tratar la diferencia en la respuesta. Por ejemplo, si se usan consultas preparadas, ¿a quién hay que recurrir para conocer el error, a `$mysqli->error` o a `$stmt->error`?

Comment: @Marcos hay algún equivalente de 'mysqli_stmt_error' para  consultas preparadas usando oracle?

Comment: @Marcos usando PDO

Comment: @Marcos buenísimo! muchas gracias por la info :D!!