# Error en consulta SQL con php pdo

Tags: php, sql

Buen día,

Tengo un error al intentar consultas una base de datos sql en php pdo esta es la sentencia:

```
 if ($tienda=="1020") {//trinidad
        $serverName = "192.168.3.89";
        $dataBase = 'OLD';       
        $uid = 'ui';
        $pwd = 'aw12';
        try {

            $conn = new PDO(
                "dblib:host=$serverName;dbname=$dataBase",
                $uid, 
                $pwd,
                array(
                    //PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                )
            );
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
        $sql ="SELECT distinct serial, equipo, max(numeroCierre)Nro_cierre_actual,MAX(fechahoraCierre) ult_fecha_cierre , (max(numeroCierre)) cierre_fiscal_faltante, ((max(numeroCierre))) tiemp_aprox_mes
            from CierreFiscal02
            where fechahoraCierre > ='23-08-2019'
             --and fechahoraCierre < '24-08-2019'
             group by serial, equipo
            order by 3 desc  
      ";
   $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $query ->execute([$factura]);

        }
```

Comment: Qué error te sale? Por favor, añádelo editando tu pregunta (enlace editar que está justo debajo de la pregunta y encima de este comentario). Copia y pega el texto

Comment: No sale error, solo que no trae ningún dato. y si ejecuto el SQL en SQL SERVER si me trae los datos

Comment: Y eso de `[$factura]` de dónde lo sacas?

Comment: @Josemoreno, puede que lo que contiene [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297988/16597) te ayude a encontrar el problema