# no guarda los registros

Tags: php, html5

No se cual es el problema pero no quiere guardar los registros en la bd y ya verifique todo y para mi esta bien pero tampoco salta un error.
aquí les dejos mi código php.
Se guardan todos los datos en las variables pero no en la Base de Datos.

```
require ("conexion.php");

     $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre);

     if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

        echo "Fallo al conectar con la BBDD";

        exit();
    }

    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

//insercion de los datos a la BD
$sql="INSERT INTO paciente(Pac_Nombres,Pac_Apellidos,Pac_Cedula,Pac_Fecha_nacimiento,Pac_Telefono,Pac_Direccion,ID_ciudad,ID_estado_civil,ID_Sexo,Pac_Alergias,Pac_Enfermedades) VALUES ('$nombre_paciente','$apellido_paciente','$cedula_paciente','$fechanacimietno_paciente','$telefono_paciente','$direccion_paciente','$ciudad_paciente','$estadocivil_paciente','$sexo_paciente','$alergia_paciente','$enfermedad_paciente')";

    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);


if ($resultado==false){
    echo "Error en la consulta:".mysqli_error($conexion);
}else{
    echo"Registro guardado";

}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: creo que te falta la conexión a la base de datos: mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");

Comment: si esta la segunda linea de código es, pero no me salta ningún error de conexión solo que no guarda

Comment: AL parecer el error esta  en esta linea:$sql="INSERT INTO paciente... No tienes los mismos parametros de inserccion en la tabla  no estas añadiendo todos los campos

Comment: Posible duplicado de [No guarda los registros en mi BD](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298969/no-guarda-los-registros-en-mi-bd)

Comment: @JMedina, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297987/c%c3%b3mo-saber-en-php-por-que-mi-consulta-sql-falla/297988#297988), puede que te sea de ayuda para detectar exactamente la razón por la que fallan tus consultas.

Comment: @Santiago estan todos los que tengo en la tabla

Comment: Imprime el error para que sepas qué es lo que pasa: **`echo "Error en la consulta:".mysqli_error($conexion);`** y, refina tu código, no tienes necesidad de esto: `mysqli_select_db($conexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la BBDD");` ¿Por qué no conectas directamente a esa BD, pasando un parámetro a la función de conexión: **`$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre);`**? Parece que te estás guiando de ejemplos muy antiguos en tu aprendizaje.

Comment: @JMedina, imprime "Error en la consulta" ? En ese cas podrías usar "mysqli_error( mysqli $link ) " para obtener la información del error.

Comment: @JMedina insisto  no esta pasando todos los parámetros correspondientes , a todos los campos de tu tabla, por favor revisa, tienes 12 campos en tu tabla y estas pasando 10 parámetros.  El campo: "Pac_Fecha_nacimiento"  no tiene su correspondiente parametro y el campo "Pac_Estado".

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias ahora cambie mi codigo y me sale el error "Error en la consulta:Incorrect date value: '' for column 'Pac_Fecha_nacimiento' at row 1"

Comment: @Santiago tenias razon, ya agregue los campos pero aun no guarda el registro

Comment: editarlo en tu publicación es bueno verlo como lo has corregido. Para buscar por otro lado

Comment: El error es claro: *`Incorrect date value for column 'Pac_Fecha_nacimiento'`* o sea, el valor que intentas ingresar en la columna `Pac_Fecha_nacimiento` no es una fecha válida. Ten en cuenta que los valores de fecha deben estar en el formato `añomesdia` por ejemplo: `20191008` o `2019-10-08` o `2019/10/08`

Comment: Puedes realizar un var_dump($sql) y copias la consulta que te muestra y la usar en phpmyadmin, así compruebas que la consulta se ejecute correctamente, yo creo que el error puede venir por que en la consulta intentas introducir un tipo de daot que no es válido en la base de datos

Comment: ahora ya esta funcionando gracias por la mano