# ¿Por qué me manda error en consulta inner join con variables de sesión?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql, php7

Estoy generando un reporte PDF que jala datos de 2 tablas de mysql, en ambas tablas existe el campo pin con el cual lo utilizo con variable de sesión para cada persona que tenga su pin pueda generarlo. Pero me esta mandando error en la consulta con la que quiero jalar los datos de ambas tablas:

```
<?php  
 session_start();
 fetch_data()  
{  
$output = '';  
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "MYDB"); 
$conn -> set_charset("utf8"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM texto_menos50 T INNER JOIN empresasregistradas E ON 
T.pin = E.pin WHERE T.pin ='{$_SESSION['pin']}' ORDER BY pin ASC";   
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  <-- El error de la linea 12
{      
$output .= 'CONTENIDO DEL PDF';}return $output;
```

El error es:

```
  Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, 
  boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\project\myproject.php on line 
  12
  TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

Comment: mmm el error mas bien parece estar cuando realizas el `fetch` y no asi en la consulta, tal vez si proporcionas un poco mas de tu código php sobre todo en el rango de la linea 12 de tu archivo `myproject.php`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297987/c%c3%b3mo-saber-en-php-por-que-mi-consulta-sql-falla)

Comment: @Israel-ICM he editado el código incluyendo la función que genera el PDF he señalado la línea 12.

Comment: @Marcos esto trabajando con consultas y variables de sesión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al parecer el error si estaba en la consulta, trata modificando el `ORDER BY` ya que no especificas de que tabla será.

Tu tienes `ORDER BY pin` cuando deberia ser `ORDER BY T.pin` o bien `E.pin` según lo que necesitas mostrar.
El sql deberia quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM texto_menos50 T INNER JOIN empresasregistradas E ON T.pin = E.pin WHERE T.pin ='{$_SESSION['pin']}' ORDER BY T.pin ASC";
```

En este caso yo puse `T.pin` para el ejemplo pero tu tendrias que poner la tabla que necesitas para realizar el `ORDER BY`.

Espero te funcione...

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, en efecto me ha funcionado. SALUDOS