# INNER JOIN con relación Muchos a muchos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo unas tablas las que tienen relación de muchos a muchos.

```
Tabla colegio

idcolegio int(10) PRI

idagno int(10) PRI

nombre text

direccion char(200)
```

```
Tabla certificado

numero_certificado int(10) PRI

nombre_profesor text

fecha char(200)
```

Y la de la relación muchos a muchos

```
Tabla certificado_colegio

id int(11) PRI auto_increment

numero_certificado int(11) MUL

idcolegio int(10) MUL
```

Lo que quiero hacer es hacer un SELECT con la tabla certificado_colegio donde me rescate los algunos datos de la tabla colegio como el nombre . Trate este SQL:

```
$sql_cole="SELECT * FROM certificado_colegio
INNER JOIN certificado_profesor ON certificado_colegio.numero_certificado = certificado_profesor.numero_certificado
INNER JOIN colegio ON certificado_colegio.idcolegio= colegio.idcolegio
WHERE numero_certificado= ?";
```

Pero me dice "Call to a member function bind_param() on bool" ¿Como lo hago para rescatar datos de la tabla colegio buscando x el numero_certificado de la tabla certificado_colegio? Lo que quiero es hacer un certificado q se imprima y en este certificado pueden haber muchos colegios y a su vez estos colegios pueden aparecer en varios certificados asi que es muchos a muchos. Gracias

Comment: Según el nombre de las tablas, lo que esta mal en la consulta es que la tabla `certificado_profesor` no existe, en su lugar deberías usar `certificado`. Puede que [esta otra públicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597) te ayude a encontrar mas rápido el error

Comment: En el `WHERE` debes especificar a qué tabla pertenece la columna `numero_certificado` ya que la misma se llama igual en dos tablas. Para abreviar la consulta sugiero que uses alias cortos. Por lo general se usa como alias la primera letra de la tabla o las primeras letras si éstas tienen nombres compuestos.

Comment: @Marcos lo de certificado_profesor fue un error al escribir, debería ser certificado pero aun así no me funciona

Comment: @FranciscaRata, lo que comento A.Cedeano también es cierto, si en el `WHERE` no indicas de que tabla `numero_certificado` estas buscando, el error que obtendrás sera `numero_certificado es ambiguo`. Revisa la respuesta en la publicación que te mencione, puede ayudarte a obtener el motivo del error al realizar consultas `SQL` en `PHP`.

Comment: @Marcos Muchas gracias! Ese era el problema. Otra consulta, la tabla colegio tiene otro campo (que no escribí) es un id de ciudad(idciudad) que tiene una relación con una tabla ciudad, yo lo que quiero es rescatar el nombre, no el id, de esta tabla, ya lo he hecho en otra consulta con un inner join pero no se si se puede llamar de una consulta  con certificado _colegio

Comment: @FranciscaRata, no utilices los comentarios para formular una nueva pregunta. [Crea una nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), describiendo lo mejor posible el escenario, el resultado que buscas obtener y lo que has intentando. **PD**, la respuesta es sí, no hay ningún problema en agregar otro `JOIN` con la tabla de ciudades