# Error en PHP: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
function sacarConsulta($sql,$conn)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH));
    {
        do
       {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH));
    }
    /*else
    {
        $data = null;
    }*/
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return ($data);
```

Que llamo a través del siguiente código:

```
$name = $_POST['user_login'];
$pass = md5($_POST['login_pass']);
$connection = Connect($config['database']);
$sql = "select * from usuarios where nombre = '".$name."'and pass = '".$pass."'";

$info = sacarConsulta($sql,$connection);
print_r ($info);
```

La función me da fallo. al sacar una consulta en las lineas donde está el `mysqli_fetch_array`, no consigo hacer la función para que me consulte si el usuario está registrando en la base de datos.

Éste es el error que recibo:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\bbdd\execute.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\bbdd\execute.php on line 21
>
> Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\bbdd\execute.php on line 27 Array
>   ( [0] => )

Comment: Puedes poner tu consulta y tu conexion a BD para que veamos que puede estar mal?

Comment: Esta pregunta se ha hecho varias veces en diferentes variaciones. Es importante ver cuál es la consulta porque contiene un error. Estoy por dar una respuesta genérica que sirva de referencia para otros usuarios.

Comment: Por cierto, el código compartido en los comentarios es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse en entornos de producción. Deberías procesar y sanear las entradas de usuario (e idealmente usar sentencias preparadas). Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP.

Comment: Puede que [la respuesta de esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597) te ayude saber porque `mysqli_query` falla al recibir la consulta `SQL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función necesita un código coherente y un control estricto del flujo.

En este ejemplo usaré claves en el array `$data` para determinar lo que haya ocurrido.

```
<?php
    function sacarConsulta($sql,$conn)
    {
        $data=array("status"=>false);
        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ) 
        {
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($count > 0) {
            $data["status"]=true;
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
                {
                    $data["content"][]=$row;
                }
            } else {
                $data["error"]="No se encontraron filas";
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);            
        } else {
                $data["error"]="Error en la consulta: {$conn->error}";
        }
    }
    return $data;
?>
```

#### Ejemplo de uso

```
$mData=sacarConsulta($sql,$conn);
if ($mData["status") 
{
    foreach ($mData["content"] as $row) 
    {
        var_dump($row); #Leer los datos
    }
} else {
    echo $mData["error"];
}
```

En el array hay tres claves: `status` con un valor `true` o `false` para saber si vienen datos o no; `error`, para indicar un mensaje de error en caso de que no vengan datos; `content`, con las diferentes filas de resultados. Este es un código portable a cualquier escenario, por ejemplo, para consumir respuestas a modo de API o en aplicaciones móviles, etc.

Quizá la función haya que adaptarla a un contexto más amplio, por ejemplo, en el caso de que se requiera usar consultas preparadas o no, pero ese es otro asunto.

Prueba de este modo y dime si funciona.

Answer (score 1):

En la [documentación de PHP para `mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) se indica que ese método:

> Retorna `FALSE` en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, `mysqli_query()` retornará un objeto [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php). Para otras consultas exitosas de `mysqli_query()` retornará `TRUE`.

Si la consulta era un SELECT (o SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN), el error que recibes quiere decir que **la consulta contiene algún tipo de error que hace que falle**. Debes revisar tu consulta (p.e. ejecutándola directamente en la base de datos) para comprobar que es correcta.

Si la consulta es diferente a esos tipos (p.e. INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE), es normal que recibas un valor booleano y este error.

Si la consulta es correcta y te sigue devolviendo un booleano (`FALSE`), eso se puede deber a que haya un error en la conexión. Verifica que la conexión a la base de datos se realizó correctamente.

Lo que puedes hacer es leer el error en tu variable de conexión para obtener información más detallada sobre el problema. Dependiendo de si usas MySQLi con objetos o de forma procedimental (en tu caso, esto último) harías:

```
mysqli_error($conn); // si usas funciones mysqli_*
```

o

```
$conn->error         // si usas objetos mysqli como objeto
```