# Error en login Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php

[image: codigo]

Estoy creando un login y cuando inicio sesion y debe llevarme al index me manda error
[codigo[image: ][1]]

cabe destacar que soy nuevo y estoy empezando como puedo

Comment: Porfavor requiero ayuda en la medida de lo posible todo sea con el fin de aprender y comprender el error y sobretodo solucionarlo y poder continuar con mi proyecto, es para mi universidad

Comment: Pues empieza leyendo este post sobre [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Una imagen con el código no es una manera correcta de compartir código. Te recomiendo que modifiques tu pregunta, incluyas el código, los errores que te da y que leas el enlace que te pasé para evitar que tus preguntas se cierren.

Comment: Además, te recomiendo que busques antes de preguntar, pues esta pregunta ha sido respondida MÚLTIPLES veces aquí mismo, y el error es siempre el mismo. Tienes un fallo en la conexión, debuggea para saber qué está mal, no asumas que todo va a funcionar.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error en PHP: mysqli\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_result, bool given](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309627/error-en-php-mysqli-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-bool)

Comment: Gracias tomaré todo los comentarios en cuenta!