# 0 results con $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Tags: php, mysqli, sql

Evidentemente estoy teniendo problemas con $result ya que me aparece en pantalla lo que escribí en el else statement: "0 results".
Debajo del código les adjunto una captura de la estructura y el contenido de la tabla de mi base de datos que verán es realmente muy simple.
Desde ya, si alguien encuentra una solución para esto se los voy a agradecer mucho!

```
$sql = "SELECT autor, frase FROM frase-autor WHERE autor = Carlos Gardel";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!empty($result) && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['autor'] . $row['frase'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

[image: El contenido de la tabla]

[image: La estructura de la tabla]

Comment: No sé mucho de mysqli, pero qué tal si intentas concatenando `$row['autor'].$row['frase'];` todo junto?

Answer (score 0):

La consulta te esta dando error, ya que has olvidado agregar comillas para evaluar `autor` igual a `Carlos Gardel`.

### Solución:

En tu caso agregando comillas simples (`'`) es suficiente.

```
$sql = "SELECT autor, frase FROM frase-autor WHERE autor = 'Carlos Gardel'";
```

**Lectura recomendada:**

- [¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297987/c%c3%b3mo-saber-en-php-por-que-mi-consulta-sql-falla)

Comment: No hay caso, no logro hacerlo funcionar :( 
Ya lo encontraré la vuelta. Gracias!