# Buscar link en una cadena de texto y reemplazarlo con PHP

Tags: php

estoy trabajando en un sistema de blog, y quiero que cuando entre el cuerpo del texto se detecte un enlace, se reemplace por un `<a>` (link) con php, probé utilizando la función : `preg_replace()` pero no me sirve, intenté con este código:

```
$msg = $_POST["msg"];
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $msg, $url)) {
       $msg = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href='{$url[0]}'>{$url[0]}</a> ", $msg);
}
```

Pero no registra el resultado en la base de datos, no me marca ningún error, dejo el código completo:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "uemjrr";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$nombre = $_POST["namemsg"];   
$foto = $_POST["foto"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $msg, $url)) {
    $msg = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href='{$url[0]}'>{$url[0]}</a> ", $msg);
}


if ($msg == "") {
    $msg = "Mensaje vacío";
}
date_default_timezone_set("America/Lima");
$fecha = date("H:i");
$_postear = "INSERT INTO mensajes (foto, nombre, mensaje, enviado) VALUES 
('$foto','$nombre','$msg','$fecha')";   
mysqli_query($conn, $_postear);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Hasta donde se [puede ver](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/338590386bae73e1a7102d95ade2e87ccce3ca4b) tu código funciona bien (_salvo que el `msg` ya tenga un `<a>` con la URL_). ¿Será que el problema esta en otro lado?

Comment: No lo sé la verdad, incluí el código completo, para ver si encontrabas algún error que esté impidiendo que se envie

Comment: ¿Será que [la consulta `SQL` falla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297987/c%c3%b3mo-saber-en-php-por-que-mi-consulta-sql-falla)? ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un ejemplo de `msg` que falla?

Comment: Falla siempre y cuando exista la palabra https

Comment: Uh, que lindo ejercicio. No es fácil la expresión regular. Lo primero que encontré, es que no funciona si el link tiene esta forma:

http://blabla.com:3000

Ahí ya no te valida el puerto. Estoy viendo una mejor expresión regular para pasarte.

Comment: @JottaArtZ ¿revisaste el enlace que te pase, para comprobar si la consulta `SQL` es lo que esta fallando? Para mi el problema esta en la línea `mysqli_query($conn, $_postear);` y seguramente es porque no estas usando [sentencias preparadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/16597)

Comment: Por ejemplo, al ingresar [https://www.example.com] simplemente no guarda nada, solo guarda si no existen enlaces

Answer (score 0):

La expresión regular que estás usando no funciona si se le pone el puerto, o query strings, etc...

Probá con esta expresión regular:

```
/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/(.[^$|\s+]*)/
```

Esa expresión regular toma todo lo que está después de http|https|ftp|ftps://, y corta en el primer espacio. Así, va a tener en cuenta el ":" del puerto de la url, los caracteres "?", "=", "%", etc... que pueden estar en el query string.

---

ACTUALIZO:
Después de mucho lidiar, encontré que quizás esta función te sirva:

```
/**
* @author Federico Saenz
*/
function addLink($content) {
    $reg_exUrl = "/.[http|https|ftp|ftps]*\:\/\/.[^$|\s]*/";
    return preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href='$0'>$0</a>", $content);
}
```

Habría que testearla muy bien. No hace falta el preg match. Si no encuentra ningún link, no te los reemplaza. Usa una expresión regular parecida a la que había hecho antes y no hace grupos. La expresión regular solamente busca links que empiecen con http, https, ftp o ftps y obtiene todo los strings que siguen hasta el primer espacio.

**Hay que testearla MUY bien**, con muchos links distintos, conformados de distinta forma, etc... Yo probé la función y anda: remplaza todo lo que sea un link http, https, ftp o ftps por el tag `<a>`. Pero hay que evaluarla en muchos casos distintos. Y hay que probarla con links inválidos (habría que leer el RFC de URL para ver cual puede ser válido o inválido: [RFC URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)). A lo sumo, habrá que agregar más reglas a la expresión regular.

Espero que te sirva. Cualquier cosa, avisá.

Este sería el snippet:
[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05e430725c10b3100271158d8d02bae3518b8e0b)

Comment: Considera explicar tu código

Comment: No va tampoco :(