# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on bool

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

Estoy haciendo un CRUD con PHP pero me salta este error. Lo he mirado muchas veces y no encuentro como solucionarlo

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on
> bool in /opt/lampp/htdocs/startnow/crud.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main}
> thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/startnow/crud.php on line 18

```
switch ($accion) {
    case "btnAgregar":

        $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios( us_nombre, us_apellido, us_correo, us_celular, us_edad, us_contrasena) values(:us_nombre, :us_apellido, :us_correo, :us_celular, :us_edad, :us_contrasena)");

        $sentencia->bindParam(':us_nombre',$txtNombre);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':us_apellido',$txtApellido);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':us_correo',$txtCorreo);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':us_celular',$txtCelular);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':id_edad',$txtEdad);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':id_contasena',$txtContrasena);
        $sentencia->execute();


        echo "Presionaste Agregar";
        break;
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297987/c%c3%b3mo-saber-en-php-por-que-mi-consulta-sql-falla)

Comment: El error ocurre porque `$setencia` es `false` (booleano) debido a que el `prepare` falló por algún motivo. Y ese motivo puede ser cualquier cosa: conexión nula, nombre de tabla o de alguna columna mal escrito  u otro. A tu código le faltan controles. Como sólo has puesto una parte de él, no se vé cómo controlas si la conexión es válida. Y en el `case`  que muestras, deberás controlar también si no hay error en la preparación y en el  `execute`. A todos esos niveles pueden ocurrir fallos y deberías controlarlos.

Answer (score 1):

El error ocurre porque `$setencia` es `false` (booleano) debido a que el `prepare` falló por algún motivo. Y ese motivo puede ser cualquier cosa: conexión nula, nombre de tabla o de alguna columna mal escrito u otro.

A tu código le faltan controles. Como sólo has puesto una parte de él, no se vé cómo controlas si la conexión es válida. Y en el `case` que muestras, deberás controlar también si no hay error en la preparación y en el  execute. A todos esos niveles pueden ocurrir fallos y deberías controlarlos.

La forma de establecer ese control sería esta:

```
#Asumimos que PREVIAMENTE controlas el estado de $conexion
switch ($accion) {
    case "btnAgregar":

        $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios( us_nombre, us_apellido, us_correo, us_celular, us_edad, us_contrasena) values(:us_nombre, :us_apellido, :us_correo, :us_celular, :us_edad, :us_contrasena)");
        if ($sentencia) {
            $sentencia->bindParam(':us_nombre',$txtNombre);
            $sentencia->bindParam(':us_apellido',$txtApellido);
            $sentencia->bindParam(':us_correo',$txtCorreo);
            $sentencia->bindParam(':us_celular',$txtCelular);
            $sentencia->bindParam(':id_edad',$txtEdad);
            $sentencia->bindParam(':id_contasena',$txtContrasena);
            #Aunque prepare sea exitoso, puede haber problemas ejecutando
            #un escenario habitual sería filas duplicadas
            #por eso controlamos también el execute
            if ($sentencia->execute()){
                $msg="Filas insertadas: ".$conexion->rowCount();
            } else {
                #Aunque no conviene mostrar errores internos del manejador
                #sacamos la info de errorInfo para depuración
                #luego lo cambias por un mensaje personalizado
                $msg="Error al insertar: ".$sentencia->errorInfo()[2];
            }
        }else{
            #Aunque no conviene mostrar errores internos del manejador
            #sacamos la info de errorInfo para depuración
            #luego lo cambias por un mensaje personalizado
            $msg="Error preparando la consulta: ".$conexion->errorInfo()[2];
        }
        break;
        #Mostramos lo que haya ocurrido
        echo $msg;
```