# Listar pedidos left join mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, tablas

tengo estas 3 tablas en mi base de datos:

**PEDIDOS:**
[image: PEDIDOS]

**PEDIDOS DETALLE:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PLATOS:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MESAS:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que deseo es listar los pedidos y mostrar la informacion de platos y mesas de cada pedido con inner join, y sumar los precios de pedidos detalle y multiplicarlos por la cantidad.
ejemplo:

```css
td{border:1px solid blue}
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black">
<tr>
<td>PEDIDO</td>
<td>TOTAL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PEDIDO 1 (id_plato,id_plato,id_plato)<br>MESA: mesa_id -</td>
<td>total de pedidos detalles (precio x cantidad)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PEDIDO 2 (id_plato,id_plato,id_plato)<br>MESA: mesa_id -</td>
<td>total de pedidos detalles (precio x cantidad)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

esto e intentado:

```
$query_pedidos = "
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(PED.precio * PED.cantidad),0) AS subtotal,
GROUP_CONCAT(PLA.nombre SEPARATOR ' - ') AS platos, 
PE.id_pedido,PE.fecha_reg,PE.estado,
MESA.nombre AS mesa
FROM pedidos_detalle PED
LEFT JOIN pedidos PE ON PE.id_pedido = PED.id_pedido
LEFT JOIN mesas MESA ON MESA.id_mesa = PE.id_mesa
LEFT JOIN platos PLA ON PLA.id_plato = PED.id_plato
WHERE PE.delet  = '0' AND PE.modalidad = '".$modo_pedidos."' AND PE.id_sucursal='".$sucursal_id."'
GROUP BY PED.id_pedido ORDER BY id_reg DESC
";
$bd_pedidos = $bd->query($query_pedidos);
```

pero me sale error

Comment: Agrega que has intentado por favor

Comment: lo olvide, gracias

Comment: Qué error te sale?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in

Comment: Es probable que el error se deba a que no has indicado exactamente la tabla de `id_reg` en el `ORDER BY`. Te recomiendo revisar [¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597)