# Actualizar datos de una tabla que esta en una base de datos de la misma tabla que está en otra base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo dos bases de datos con una única tabla cada 1

```
--usuarios base 1-----  ---usuarios base 2----
|  id  |  Nombre  |    |  id  |  Nombre      |
-------------------    -----------------------
|  1   |  Luis    |    |  1   | Luis         |
|  2   |  Juan    |    |  2   | Juan         |
|  3   |  Pedro   |    -----------------------
-------------------
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es tomar los registros que estan en la base1 y copiarlos en la base2
esto es parte de lo que he realizado pero sigo sin tener resultado

```
$usnd = "root";
$psbd = "";
$lc = "localhost";

$bd1 = "tabla_1";
$bd2 = "tabla_2";

$conn = mysqli_connect($lc,$usnd,$psbd);
$tbname = "usuarios";

$sql_query = "INSERT INTO $bd2.$tbname (SELECT * FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN $bd2.$tbname ON $bd2.$tbname.id = $bd.$tbname.id WHERE $bd2.$tbname.id IS NULL)";
$get_result = $conn->query($sql_query);
```

Comment: Necesitaríás dos conexiones, una a cada BD; jalar los datos de una y luego insertarlos. Para hacer un insert into select, LAS DOS BD se tienen que ver entre sí. Es lo que llaman dblink, linked server o similar en otros motores. Tendrías que buscar cómo hacerlo en mysql. Las dos BD están en la misma instancia de MySQL?

Comment: No estoy seguro si necesitas dos conexiones (nunca lo he probado desde PHP). Pero si el usuario con el que te has conectado tiene privilegios en ambas BD, podría funcionar. Conviene que captures el mensaje de error que estás recibiendo para poder analizar con más propiedad el problema. Por ejemplo, pueden ocurrir errores de clave duplicada, de violación de NOT NULL, de integridad referencial u otros. De todos modos, no le veo sentido a lo que quieres hacer usando código PHP. Si se trata de normalizar, hazlo en el manejador directamente, si se trata de sincronizar, programa un TRIGGER.

Comment: Considero que el comentario de @A.Cedano es muy acertado. Además creo que el error se debe a que en el `SELECT` no has indicado la BD del `FROM`, es decir, debería ser `SELECT * FROM $bd1.$tbname ...`. Te recomiendo revisar [¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597)