# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Hola tengo un pequeño sistema que hice para que consulte la base de datos de codeigniter y me arroje los datos de unas órdenes de servicio... en el localhost funciona bien, pero al subirla al hosting marca error 500 cabe recalcar que el hosting usa php 7.3 y el xammp (localhost) usa el mismo PHP 7.3

la verdad me tiene loco no entiendo que tengo mal.. el error log de cpanel dice esto:

```
[19-Feb-2021 05:26:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in /home/sistegra/public_html/stecnico/consultaros/pages/tables/data.php:83
```

Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /home/sistegra/public_html/stecnico/consultaros/pages/tables/data.php on line 83

y mi código es este...

```
        <?php 
    
        $nombre_Cliente = NULL;
    
        $buscarPor = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Criterio', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
        $where = trim(strtolower(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'itBuscar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))); 

        $buscar = true;
        if (empty($where)) 
        {
           $buscar = false;                   
        }
        if ($buscarPor === 'Email')
        {
            if(!filter_var($where, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))  
            {
                $buscar = false;                    
            }
        }

        $sq1 = "SELECT OS.IDOS, CLI.NOMECLIENTE, OS.DATAINICIAL, OS.DATAFINAL, OS.STATUS, OS.OBSERVACOES, OS.LAUDOTECNICO
                FROM clientes CLI
                INNER JOIN OS ON OS.Clientes_id = CLI.idClientes";       

        if ($buscar)
        {  
            $datoBuscar = "'".$where."'";
            if ($buscarPor === 'Documento') 
            {                    
               $query = $sq1. " WHERE CLI.documento = $datoBuscar";
            }
            else                
            {
                $query = $sq1. " WHERE CLI.email = $datoBuscar";
            }
            $cn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'stecnico');        
            $rs = $cn->query($query);
            $rs = $cn->query($query);
            $nombre_Cliente = $rs->fetch_assoc()['NOMECLIENTE'];                  
            $vecresultado = array(); 
            while ($fila = $rs->fetch_row()) 
            {                   
               //$nombre_Cliente = ($fila[1]);
               array_push($vecresultado, $fila);
            }

            mysqli_free_result($rs);
            mysqli_close($cn);
            }
        else 
        {   
             header("Location: /stecnico/consultaros/index.php?Error=s"); 
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297987/c%c3%b3mo-saber-en-php-por-que-mi-consulta-sql-falla)

Comment: podrías aclararme como puedo aplicar esto a mi problema?.

añadí el siguien código                 

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

ahora me muestra tal vez un error más claro.

[19-Feb-2021 13:06:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'sistegra_banco.OS' doesn't exist in /home/sistegra/public_html/stecnico/consultaros/pages/tables/data.php:81

Com que intenta conectar a sistegra_banco.OS y claro ese nombre de base de datos no existe el nombre correcto es sistegra_banco, que puede ser el problema?

Comment: Tendrías que ejecutarlo con `$ch->error()`. Por otro lado, por qué el código `$rs = $cn->query($query);` está repetido?. Te recomendaría también ejecutar un `fetch_array()` entes de una obtención asociativa

Comment: @RicReyRey, en el código que compartes, no aparece `sistegra_banco`. Seguramente el error esta en otro lado.

Comment: @RicReyRey, Creo que te faltó definir el nombre de la tabla en la consulta. `... FROM clientes CLI INNER JOIN OS ON ...` en esta parte puedo inferir que solo estas usando el alias pero no dices que tabla es, por lo que la consulta intenta buscar la tabla OS, que por lo que reportas OS no exsite en la base de datos. aqui faltaría especificar que tabla es OS `... INNER JOIN table_name OS ON ...`