# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: php, php7

Hola soy nuevo en esto de la programación, y me sale el error:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Me señala que el error se encuentra específicamente en la siguiente línea:

```
if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["usuario-Ing"] && $respuesta["clave"] == $_POST["clave-Ing"]){
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public function IngresoUsuariosC(){
    if(isset($_POST["usuario-Ing"])){
        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["usuario-Ing"]) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["clave-Ing"])){

            $datosC = array("usuario"=>$_POST["usuario-Ing"], "clave"=>$_POST["clave-Ing"]);

            $tablaBD = "usuarios";
            $respuesta = UsuariosM::IngresoUsuariosM($datosC, $tablaBD);

            if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["usuario-Ing"] && $respuesta["clave"] == $_POST["clave-Ing"]){

                $_SESSION["Ingreso"] = true;                    
                $_SESSION["id"] = $respuesta["id"];
                $_SESSION["usuario"] = $respuesta["usuario"];
                $_SESSION["clave"] = $respuesta["clave"];
                $_SESSION["foto"] = $respuesta["foto"];
                $_SESSION["rol"] = $respuesta["rol"];

                echo '<script>

                    window.location = "inicio";
                    </script>';
            }else{
                echo 'ERROR AL INGRESAR';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parece que la variable `$respuesta` no es un arreglo, sino un booleano. Puede que [esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597) te ayude a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar lo siguiente

```
public function IngresoUsuariosC(){
    if(isset($_POST["usuario-Ing"])){
        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["usuario-Ing"]) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["clave-Ing"])){

            $datosC = array("usuario"=>$_POST["usuario-Ing"], "clave"=>$_POST["clave-Ing"]);

            $tablaBD = "usuarios";
            $respuesta = UsuariosM::IngresoUsuariosM($datosC, $tablaBD);

            if(is_array($respuesta["usuario"]) == $_POST["usuario-Ing"] && $respuesta["clave"] == $_POST["clave-Ing"]){

                $_SESSION["Ingreso"] = true;                    
                $_SESSION["id"] = $respuesta["id"];
                $_SESSION["usuario"] = $respuesta["usuario"];
                $_SESSION["clave"] = $respuesta["clave"];
                $_SESSION["foto"] = $respuesta["foto"];
                $_SESSION["rol"] = $respuesta["rol"];

                echo '<script>

                    window.location = "inicio";
                    </script>';
            }else{
                echo 'ERROR AL INGRESAR';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simplemente agrega:

is_array($respuesta["usuario"])

Comment: Hola Edgar, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.