# Error fatal : Error no detectado: llamada a una función miembro fetchInto () en php

Tags: javascript, php

estoy tratando de catualizar componentes viejos de php pero me aparece el siguiente error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchInto() on bool in /opt/lampp/htdocs/trabajo/calls/dats.php:570 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/trabajo/calls/dats.php(208): asternic_report('outgoing') #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/trabajo/calls/dats.php on line 570

mi codigo es desde la 570 hasta 658

```
while ($res->fetchInto($row, DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {

//        if($row['accountcode']=="") {
            $row['accountcode']="Default";
//        }

        if(!isset($number_in_calls[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']])) {
            $number_in_calls[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]=0;
        }
        $number_in_calls[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]++;
    }


    $query = "SELECT substring($chanfield,1,locate(\"-\",$chanfield,length($chanfield)-8)-1) AS chan1,";
    //$query = "SELECT IF($chanfield like 'Local/%',CONCAT('SIP',RIGHT(substring(replace($chanfield,'-','/'),1,instr($chanfield,'@')-1),instr(reverse(substring(replace($chanfield,'-','/'),1,instr($chanfield,'@')-1)),'/'))),substring($chanfield,1,locate(\"-\",$chanfield,length($chanfield)-8)-1)) as chan1, ";
    $query.= "billsec,duration,duration-billsec as ringtime,src,dst,calldate,disposition,accountcode FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr ";
    $query.= "WHERE calldate >= '$start' AND calldate <= '$end' AND (duration-billsec) >=0 $condicionextra ";
    $query.= "HAVING chan1 in ($extension) order by null";

    $res = $db->query($query);

    if(DB::IsError($res)) {
        die($res->getMessage());
    }

    $total_calls = 0;
    $total_bill  = 0;
    $total_ring  = 0;

    while ($res->mysql_fetch_array($row, DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {

//        if($row['accountcode']=="") {
            $row['accountcode']="Default";
//        }

        if(!in_array($row['accountcode'],$departments)) {
            array_push($departments,$row['accountcode']);
            $group_bill[$row['accountcode']]  = 0;
            $group_ring[$row['accountcode']]  = 0;
            $group_calls[$row['accountcode']] = 0;
        }

        if(!isset($billsec[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']])) {
            $billsec[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]      = 0;
            $duration[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]     = 0;
            $ringing[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]      = 0;
            $number_calls[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']] = 0;
            $missed[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]       = 0;
        }
        if(!isset($number_in_calls[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']])) {
            $number_in_calls[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]=0;
        }

        $billsec[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]  += $row['billsec'];
        $duration[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']] += $row['duration'];
        $number_calls[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]++;

        if(!isset($missed[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']])) { $missed[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]=0; }
        $ringing[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]+=$row['ringtime'];
        $total_bill+=$row['billsec'];
        $total_ring+=$row['ringtime'];
        $total_calls++;

        $group_bill[$row['accountcode']]+=$row['billsec'];
        $group_ring[$row['accountcode']]+=$row['ringtime'];
        $group_calls[$row['accountcode']]++;

        $disposition = $row['disposition'];

        if($disposition<>"ANSWERED" ) {
          $missed[$row['accountcode']][$row['chan1']]++;
        }
    }

    if($total_calls > 0) {
        $avg_ring_full = $total_ring / $total_calls;
    } else {
        $avg_ring_full = 0;
    }

    $avg_ring_full = number_format($avg_ring_full,0);

    $total_bill_print = seconds2minutes($total_bill);

    $start_parts = split(" ", $start);
    $end_parts   = split(" ", $end);

    require_once("menu.php");
?>
```

al parecer la propiedad fetchInto esta obsoleta o no se cual es
pero la mayoria de los querys estan orientados a objetos entonces necesito hechar andar ese pequeño codigo para mostrar mas detalles y datos dentro de una tabla la cual me hace un cont general para mis servicios que necesito

Comment: Al parecer la variable `$res` es un booleano. Puede que esta [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597) te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Aunque no conozco el método `fetchInto()` ... El error *`Call to a member function fetchInto() on bool`* ocurre porque `$res` es un booleano (sin duda `false`) debido a que la consulta que ejecutaste y cuyo resultado quisiste obtener en `$res` ha fallado por algún motivo. Entonces debes revisar esa consulta, verificar si tienes conexión, etc.