# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool no encuentro la solucion

Tags: php, mysql

alguien me puede ayudar con esto no encuentro el error.
lo que estoy intentando hacer es simplemente agregar un nuevo registro a la base de datos por el metodo get.

```
  <?php
include 'conexion.php';
$nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
$apellido=$_GET['apellido'];

//$nombre="mateo";
//apellido="gallego";

$sentencia=$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba VALUES (?, ?)");
$sentencia->bind_param('ss',$nombre,$apellido);
$sentencia->execute();

$resultado = $sentencia->get_result();
if ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);     
}
$sentencia->close();
$conexion->close();
?>
```

y esta es la conexion de la base de datos

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$database = 'detalles_egallego_gestion';
$usernamebase = "root";
$passwordbase = "";

$conexion=new mysqli($hostname, $usernamebase, $passwordbase, $database);
$conexion->set_charset("utf8");
if ($conexion->connect_errno){
    echo "el sitio web esta presentando problemas";
}

?>
```

muchas gracias al que pueda ayudarme

Comment: haz intentado con $sql = "INSERT INTO `prueba` SET `nombre`=?,`apellido`=?"; , claro con los campos de tu base de datos

Comment: ¿La tabla `prueba` tiene **sólo dos** columnas tipo `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Puede que [este articulo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597) te sea de ayuda