# Como escribir varias filas en SQL con php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de escribir en dos tablas diferentes con un solo formulario, con este código si me manda las imágenes a la carpeta pero no me escribe en la base de datos.

Estoy desarrollando una página personal dinámica para practicar.
Agradezco la ayuda

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    //guardar inputs en variables 
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    


    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `portfolio`(`nombre`,`categoria`, `descripcion`)
    VALUES ('$nombre','$categoria','$descripcion')");

    $idPortfolio = mysqli_insert_id();

    foreach($_FILES["imagen"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
        $imagen = $_FILES['imagen'];
        
        $img_loc = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'][$key];
        
        
        $img_name = $_FILES['imagen']['name'][$key];
        
        
        move_uploaded_file($img_loc,'../upload/'.$img_name);


        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `portfolio_img`(`img`, `id_portfolio`)
        VALUES ('$img_name','$idPortfolio')");

 }
    header('Location:../admin/portfolio.php?success');
}
?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597)

Comment: veo raro que en tus consultas (ambas) no dejes espacio entre el nombre de la tabla y el paréntesis. Siguiendo la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) ponen esto: `INSERT INTO tbl_name () VALUES();` y allí si veo el espacio. Prueba a separar con un espacio eso a ver si así funciona (aunque en una respuesta que te han dado no les ha causado problema, pero por si acaso pruebalo).

Answer (score 0):

decidí intentarlo por mi cuenta y no tuve ningún problema para que la información fuese añadida a la base de datos, por lo que probablemente el error se encuentre en otro lugar. Para hacerlo, creé 3 archivos, los cuales puedes utilizar para comprobar el funcionamiento y los mencionaré a continuación:

**form.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<form action="enviardatos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"></p>
<p>Descripción: <input type="text" name="descripcion"></p>
<p>Categoría: <input type="text" name="categoria"></p>
<p>Imágenes:</p>
<p><input type="file" name="imagen[]" /></p>
<p><input type="file" name="imagen[]" /></p>
<p><input type="file" name="imagen[]" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></p>
<input type="hidden" name="insert">
</form>
</html>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "usuario", "contraseña", "basededatos");
?>
```

**enviardatos.php**

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    //guardar inputs en variables 
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    


    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `portfolio`(`nombre`,`categoria`, `descripcion`)
    VALUES ('$nombre','$categoria','$descripcion')");

    $idPortfolio = mysqli_insert_id($con);

    foreach($_FILES["imagen"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
        $imagen = $_FILES['imagen'];
        
        $img_loc = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'][$key];
        
        
        $img_name = $_FILES['imagen']['name'][$key];
        
        
        move_uploaded_file($img_loc,'../upload/'.$img_name);


        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `portfolio_img`(`img`, `id_portfolio`)
        VALUES ('$img_name','$idPortfolio')");

 }
    header('Location:../admin/portfolio.php?success');
}
?>
```

Solo modifiqué la línea que utiliza la función [mysqli_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) ya que requiere un parámetro para el estilo por procedimientos, que es el que estás utilizando. Antes de eso mostraba una advertencia como la siguiente:

Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\enviardatos.php on line 16

La cual no detiene la ejecución del script y, por lo tanto, no impide que se registren los datos en la base de datos, pero puede llegar a causar problemas en el futuro. Puedes ver esta advertencia eliminando la siguiente línea del archivo **enviardatos.php**:

```
    header('Location:../admin/portfolio.php?success');
```

Además de todo lo mencionado anteriormente, ten en cuenta que la página que estás desarrollando es vulnerable a la inyección SQL, por lo que puedes utilizar las [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) para prevenirlo.