# No se insertan los datos en mi base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Tengo un problema, cuando intento guardar datos de mi formulario no se guardan. Creí que usar el mismo código que use para el login funcionaria.
Estoy usando Bootstrap v4.3, Jquery v3.6, SweetAlert2.

Este es mi formulario, solo agrego una parte del formulario para no hacer muy extenso el codigo.

```
            <form class="form-neon FormularioAjax" action="" method="POST" data-form="save" autocomplete="off"
                    id="formcashier">
                    <input type="hidden" name="modulo_caja" value="registrar">
                    <fieldset>                       
                        <div class="container-fluid">          
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="caja_numero" class="bmd-label-floating">Numero de caja &nbsp; <i
                                                class="fab fa-font-awesome-alt"></i> &nbsp;</label>
                                        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{1,5}" class="form-control"
                                            name="caja_numero_reg" id="caja_numero" maxlength="5">
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                                      
                    </fieldset>                 
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-info btn-sm"><i
                            class="far fa-save"></i> &nbsp;
                        GUARDAR</input>
                    </p>
                </form>
```

Este es el script que estoy usando para enviar los datos, aqui pongo todos id que tengo en el formulario.

```
$('#formcashier').submit(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var caja_numero=$.trim($('#caja_numero').val());
    var caja_nombre=$.trim($('#caja_nombre').val());
    var caja_estado=$.trim($('#caja_estado').val());
    var caja_efectivo=$.trim($('#caja_efectivo').val());

    if(caja_numero.length =="" || caja_nombre == "" || caja_estado==""|| caja_efectivo=="" ){
       Swal.fire({
           icon:'error',
           title:'No hay datos ingresados!',});
           return false;
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url:'../../database/cashierNew.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{caja_numero:caja_numero, caja_nombre:caja_nombre , caja_estado:caja_estado, caja_efectivo:caja_efectivo},
            success: function(data){
                if(data=="null"){
                    Swal.fire({
                        type:'error',
                        title:'Usuarna incorrecta',
                    });
                }else{
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon:'success', 
                        title:'exitosa',
                        comfirmButtonColor:'red',
                        comfirmButtonText:'Ingresar'
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location.href = "views/pag_inicio.php";
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Y este es el PHP que debe almacenar los datos, la parte comentada es parecida a la del login pero no use esa, si no la otra que esta abajo.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include_once 'conexion.php';
    $objeto = new Conexion(); 
    $conexion = $objeto->Conectar();


    /**Recepcion de datos enviados por medio de POST por AJAX
    $caja_numero = (isset($_POST['caja_numero'])) ? $_POST['caja_numero'] : '';
    $caja_nombre = (isset($_POST['caja_nombre'])) ? $_POST['caja_nombre'] : '';
    $caja_estado = (isset($_POST['caja_estado'])) ? $_POST['caja_estado'] : '';
    $caja_efectivo = (isset($_POST['caja_efectivo'])) ? $_POST['caja_efectivo'] : '';
    */

    $caja_numero = $_POST['caja_numero'];
    $caja_nombre = $_POST['caja_nombre'];
    $caja_estado = $_POST['caja_estado'];
    $caja_efectivo = $_POST['caja_efectivo'];
   
    $insertar = "INSERT INTO cashier_new (id, num_caja, nomb_caja, estado_caja, efect_caja) VALUES (null, '".$caja_numero."','".$caja_nombre."','".$caja_estado."','".$caja_efectivo."')";
    $resultado = $conexion->prepare($insertar);
    $resultado -> execute();


    $conexion = null;
?>
```

Comment: Primero, tu `PHP` no devuelve nada, porque lo que siempre va a salir el mensaje de error. Segundo, si to consulta esta fallando, puede que [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297987/16597) te se de ayuda.

Comment: Tu problema es lo que yo llamo *programación ingenua* o *programación optimista*. Consiste en escribir código pensando que el mundo es color de rosa, **sin controlar ningún posible error**. En un contexto tan simple como este **al menos 5 errores pueden ocurrir**: 1. Que los datos lleguen en blanco, 2. Que no haya conexión, 3. Que la consulta tenga error de sintaxis, 4. Que la consulta sea correcta, pero que falle por una clave duplicada, 5. Que la consulta sea correcta pero que viole algún tipo de restricción ... En tu *programación optimista* no estás considerando/controlando ningún error.

Comment: La misma *programación optimista* te lleva a creer que **todo el mundo usará tu formulario para introducir los datos que tú crees**. Pues **NO**, un hacker puede usar ese formulario para tomar el control de tu servidor ... Sí, se llama *inyección SQL*, y a través de ella, te pueden incluso meter un troyano en el mismo servidor, modificar/alterar datos, obtener información sensible, etc. Deberías por tanto usar **consultas preparadas**. Por otra parte, **tu código PHP no es coherente** con respecto al cliente. Allí tú evalúas esto: `if(data=="null"){` pero, `data` no será eso necesariamente.