# ¿Por qué no se registra el usuario en la base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql

He revisado el código HTML y el código en PHP y no sé que se me puede estar escapando, la página recarga y no hay mensaje de error, pero el registro no se ve reflejado en la base de datos.

```
if($errores == ''){
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO users (id,nombre,correo,area,userred,passred,idanydesk,passanydesk,userGoogle,passGoogle,userMicrosoft,passMicrosoft,
    useriCLoud,passiCloud,piniPhone) VALUES (null,:nombre,:correo,:area,:userred,:passred,:idanydesk,:passanydesk,:userGoogle,:passGoogle,:userMicrosoft,:passMicrosoft,
    :useriCloud,:passiCloud,:piniPhone)');
    $statement->execute(array(':nombre' =>$nombre, ':correo'=>$correo,':area', ':userred'=>$userred,':passred'=>$passred,':idanydesk'=>$idanydesk,':passanydesk'=>$passanydesk,
    ':userGoogle'=>$userGoogle,':passGoogle'=>$passGoogle,':userMicrosoft'=>$userMicrosoft,':passMicrosoft'=>$passMicrosoft,':useriCloud'=>$useriCloud,':passiCloud'=>$passiCloud,
    ':piniphone'=>$piniPhone))
```

Comment: Agrega el mysqli_error a ver si arroja algo, y revisa los logs de la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297987/c%c3%b3mo-saber-en-php-por-que-mi-consulta-sql-falla)

Comment: Hay un error tipográfico en `$statement->execute( ... )`, en la parte de `... ':area' ...` solo está la clave sin su valor.

Comment: Revisa si el problema esta cuando incluyes en la sentencia el id ya que yo por lo general no agrego el id ya que este se agrega automáticamente, tseria quitar id y el null de las sentencias

Answer (score 0):

Te falta en el ejecutar el valor del area, espero que te sirva

```
if($errores == ''){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO users (id,nombre,correo,area,userred,passred,idanydesk,passanydesk,userGoogle,passGoogle,userMicrosoft,passMicrosoft,
        useriCLoud,passiCloud,piniPhone) VALUES (null,:nombre,:correo,:area,:userred,:passred,:idanydesk,:passanydesk,:userGoogle,:passGoogle,:userMicrosoft,:passMicrosoft,
        :useriCloud,:passiCloud,:piniPhone)');
       
     $statement->execute(array(':nombre' =>$nombre, ':correo'=>$correo,':area'=>$area, ':userred'=>$userred,':passred'=>$passred,':idanydesk'=>$idanydesk,':passanydesk'=>$passanydesk,':userGoogle'=>$userGoogle,':passGoogle'=>$passGoogle,':userMicrosoft'=>$userMicrosoft,':passMicrosoft'=>$passMicrosoft,':useriCloud'=>$useriCloud,':passiCloud'=>$passiCloud,
            ':piniphone'=>$piniPhone));
        }
```