# Consultas preparadas mysqli solo funcionan trabajando en local

Tags: php, sql

Pues resulta que estoy desarrollando en local, todo funciona bien, pero al subir el proyecto al servidor, me saltan estos errores donde estoy usando las consultas preparadas:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in /home/airlines/public_html/test/porra-final/includes/app.php:41 Stack trace: #0 /home/airlines/public_html/test/porra-final/procesar-login.php(12): App->login('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx') #1 {main} thrown in /home/airlines/public_html/test/porra-final/includes/app.php on line 41
```

Justo este error hace referencia a:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $pass);
```

en:

```
$pass = md5($password);
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? and pass = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    $_SESSION["login"] = true;
    return true;
}
```

Lo cual insisto en local me funciona correctamente. Y por supuesto los datos de acceso a la base de datos están correctamente.

Tengo que recurrir a las consultas dinámicas no seguras mysqli para que no me salten esos errores...

Comment: es la misma base de datos?

Comment: Verificaste que version de php maneja el hosting?

Comment: @ernestojimenez justo hoy he probado a ponerle la version 7.2 de PHP y sigue pasando lo mismo, es como si devolviera false en vez de true, pero el tema es que en localhost funciona todo a la perfección y en el servidor no

Comment: @gbianchi los datos son a otra BBDD pero los datos están cambiados correctamente

Comment: Después de preparar la consulta agrega `var_dump($this->con, $stmt, $this->con->error);` y edita la pregunta para poner el resultado.

Comment: @Rodrypaladin imagino que en la cabecera del PHP tienes un ``ìnclude``  para la conexion, puedes confirmar que en desarrollo existe ? o en cualquier caso, agreganos como creas la conexion.

Comment: si funciona en un entorno y en otro no, verifica que el driver tenga acceso al servidor de db, en líneas generales `localhost` no es lo mismo que la ip `127.0.0.1` / `::1` y (según la versión de la db) usando `localhost` la conexion es via socket mientras que usando ip la conexion es con ip/puerto ver los granted ver el firewall etc.. [`mysqli_get_host_info($enlace)`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) te puede dar una pista

Comment: hola buenas, consulta, las rutas que estan ahi corresponden a las del servidor? saludos

Comment: en tu código no colocas que driver usas... y lo que dice el error es que el bim_param no forma parte del driver que estas usando...

Comment: para hacer debug paso a paso muestra el valor de $stmt antes de hacer bim param y compara lo que sale en local y el host

Comment: el. hecho que no funcione en el host y en el local es por que algo debe haber diferente que no has encontrado...

Comment: recomiendo uses PDO

Comment: Funciona en local y subiste el proyecto a un servidor, ¿En el servidor creaste otra base de datos y puedes acceder a ella con alguna herramienta de administración?.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean** es por  que $stmt vale false (un valor booleano, no un recurso mysqli) Por que en este caso se produjo un error en el prepare. Es posible que no se haya podido conectar por lo tanto no pudo "preparar la consulta" y eso conlleva a que sea nulo y no se pueda bindear los parametros.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Entonces por qué en localhost funciona correctamente pero al subirlo al servidor y poner los datos de acceso a la BBDD y la tabla correctamente aparece el error ?

Comment: @Rodrypaladin, puede que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297988/16597) te ayude a encontrarlo. El error puede deberse desde que la tabla no existe hasta un nombre de columna.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la función call_user_func_array para pasar los parámetros a bind_param

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque la variable `stmt` no es un objeto de sentencia sino un valor booleano, que probablemente sea `false`.

Cito textual la documentación de [mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php):

> mysqli_prepare() devuelve un objeto de sentencia o **false** si ocurre un error.

Podrías hacer uso de algunas de las propiedades que ofrece Mysqli para conocer el error.

- [mysqli::$connect_errno](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.connect-errno.php) - Devuelve el código de error de la última llamada
- [mysqli::$connect_error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.connect-error.php) - Devuelve una cadena con la descripción del último error de conexión
- [mysqli::$errno](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.errno.php) — Devuelve el código del error de la última función llamada
- [mysqli::$error_list](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error-list.php) — Devuelve una lista de errores desde el último comando ejecutado
- [mysqli::$error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) — Devuelve una cadena que describe el último error
- [mysqli::$sqlstate](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.sqlstate.php) — Devuelve el error SQLSTATE de la operación de MySQL previa

Comment: Y por qué en localhost funciona perfectamente pero al subirlo al servidor con los datos de acceso a la BBDD y a la tabla tira este error ?

Comment: @Rodrypaladin usá algunas de las propiedades que te puse arriba para saber qué error lanza. En local no te va a aparecer nada (supongo). Por eso hacé depuración y fijate en el servidor donde está alojado. Puede ser que en el servidor haya algo que se está pasando de largo. Una vez hecho si te indica algún error que desconoces editá tu pregunta y agregá el log de errores para que te podamos ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

lo que quieres hacer es comprobar que el usuario y contraseña?

No sé si te sirva esto. Pero hago una validación de login con esto usando mysqli y php

```
<?php
//session_start();
include 'includes/conexion.php';  // la clase donde tienes tus datos conexion a la bd
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT *
FROM
  `siref_usuarios`
    INNER JOIN `siref_tipo_usuarios` 
        ON (`siref_usuarios`.`siref_tipo_usuarios_id_tipo_user` = `siref_tipo_usuarios`.`id_tipo_user`)where nombre_usuario='$user' and pass='$pass'") or die("<p> No se ha podido ejecutar la consulta. Compruebe si la sintaxis de la misma es correcta" . mysqli_error($conexion) . "-->Valida usuario<p>");

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

if (empty($result)) {

    header('Location:../pages/login.php?dato=error');
} else {
    if ($result['activo'] == 'n') {
        echo"<script>alert('Este usuario esta Desabilitado ')</script>";
    } else {
        if ($user == $result['nombre_usuario'] && $pass == $result['pass']) {
            session_start();

            $ciclo = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * from siref_ciclo WHERE activo='1'") or die("<p> No se ha podido ejecutar la consulta. Compruebe si la sintaxis de la misma es correcta" . mysqli_error($conexion) . "--> alumnos.php<p>");
            $resultciclo = mysqli_fetch_array($ciclo);
            

            $_SESSION['nombre_usuario_logeado'] = $result['nombre_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['nombre_comp'] = $result['nombre_completo'];
            $_SESSION['id_tipo_user'] = $result['id_tipo_user'];
            $_SESSION['idusuario'] = $result['id_usuarios'];           
            $_SESSION['nombre_tipo'] = $result['nom_tipo'];            
            $_SESSION['ciclo'] = $resultciclo['nom_clico'];                        
            $_SESSION['idciclo'] = $resultciclo['id_ciclo'];    
            $_SESSION['idcampus'] = $result['siref_campus_id_campus']; 
              //se agrega una nueva sesion de campus
            $_SESSION['campus'] = $result['siref_campus_id_campus'];
            $fecha = date('Y/m/d');
            $hora = date("G:i:s");
            $idusuario=$result['id_usuarios'];




            $sesiones = "INSERT INTO `siref_sesiones`
            (`id_sesion`,
             `siref_usuarios_id_usuarios`,
             `fecha_sesion`,
             `hora_sesion`)
    values
    (0,'$idusuario' ,'$fecha', '$hora')";

            $insert = mysqli_query($conexion,$sesiones) or die("<p>No se ha podido ejecutar la consultas. Compruebe si la sintaxis de la misma es correcta" . mysqli_error($conexion) . "-->insertar llamada-->edit_entry.php<p>");
if($result['id_tipo_user']==1 || $result['id_tipo_user']==3 || $result['id_tipo_user']==4){
                //echo "<script> document.location=('reportehoy.php')</script>";
     echo "<script> document.location=('index.php')</script>";
}else{
            echo "<script> document.location=('index.php')</script>";
}
        }
    }
}
```

trata de modificarlo para tu beneficio, no sé si fui de ayuda.

Comment: No es una respuesta. No se basa en la pregunta y publica un codigo con comentario tipo "a mi me sitvió con esto"