# Ciclo for no funciona

Tags: mysql, php7

Tengo un problema, por alguna razón no inserta en la base de datos (MySQL) este ciclo for que tengo llamando un procedimiento almacenado. El objetivo es insertar en la base de datos el identificador del expediente médico del paciente, identificador del paciente, el medicamento que ha consumido, dosis y la fecha de inicio. En la tabla no hay identificador auto generado, ya que es una tabla de detalle. Lamentablemente, no hay mensaje de error porque simplemente no lanza ninguno.

Ya verifiqué el procedimiento almacenado, funciona. Si hay identificadores, es decir, no viene nula la información (los cuales como regla no deben de ir nulos). El código es el siguiente:

Tabla: Detalle_Medicamentos_Medicina_general
Id_expediente   int,
Id_paciente     int,
Medicamento     Varchar(75),
Dosis_Med       Varchar(15),
Fecha_ini_Med   Date

Este es el código PHP:

```
for($t=0;$t<$contador4;$t++) {    
              $datosx3  = array ("Id_expediente"=> ([$idlast])[$t],
              "Id_paciente"=>([$Id_paciente])[$t],
              "Medicamento" => ([$Medicamento_1])[$t],
              "Dosis_Med" =>([$Dosis_Med_1])[$t],
              "Fecha_ini_Med"=> ([$Fecha_ini_Med_1])[$t]); 

              $statemenx3 = $conexion8 ->prepare("CALL SP_Insertar_Hist_Med_Gen_Medicmantos_Actuales(?, ?, 
              ?, ?, ?)");     
                
              $statemenx3 -> bind_param("iissss", $datosx3["Id_expediente"],
              $datosx3["Id_paciente"],$datosx3["Medicamento"],
              $datosx3["Dosis_Med"], $datosx3["Fecha_ini_Med"]);
              $statemenx3 -> execute(); //Se ejecuta toda la consulta             
              }
              $statemenx3 -> close(); // Se cierra el estatuto             
              $conexion10->close(); // Se cierra la conexión a la BD 



 $ProContador=0;
                     $query = "INSERT INTO hist_med_gen_antedent_here_yfam(Id_expediente, Id_paciente, Pedecimiento_hereditario_familiar, Id_Tipo_familiar) VALUES ";
                     $queryValue = "";
                      for($i=0;$i<$contador;$i++) {
                         if(!empty($_POST[$idlast][$i]) || !empty($_POST["txtIdpaciente"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["txtantecedentes1"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["CboFamiliar1"][$i])) 
                         {
                            $ProContador++;
                            if($queryValue!="")
                            {
                               $queryValue .= ",";
                            }
                             $queryValue .= "('" . [$idlast][$i] . "'," . $_POST["txtIdpaciente"][$i] . "'," . $_POST["txtantecedentes1"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["CboFamiliar1"][$i] . "')";
                         }
                     } 
                     $sql = $query.$queryValue;
                     $sql2 = substr($query.$queryValue, 0, -1);                                                 
                     if($ProContador!=0) {
                       $resultadocon = mysqli_query($conexion4, $sql);
                       print "<script>alert(\"Se Guardó Correctamente: Los Antecedentes Hereditarios y Familiares. \");</script>";
                     }
```

El ultimo código es un ciclo que estoy experimentando, pero, tampoco funciona adecuadamente. Por alguna razón insertó, pero lo hace de manera errónea, adjunto imagen del resultado (no sé porque en el nombre del padecimiento inserta "Array"). En fin, no encuentro mi error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Estoy usando el método $_POST. El editor que estoy utilizando es: Visual Studio Code y Wampserver. Saludos y gracias, por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Por qué no crear la sentencia preparada fuera del `for`? Tu SP acepta 5 parámetros pero estás indicando 6 en el bind (_`iissss` <- son 6_). Te dejo [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297987/c%c3%b3mo-saber-en-php-por-que-mi-consulta-sql-falla) a pregunta la cual puede que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Hola, Marcos. Gracias, por tu respuesta, pero, lamentablemente no puedo usar por regla un scrip para insertar así; tengo que usar un SP. Y si, en el tema del bind estaba mal. Lo corregí, pero sigue sin insertar. Francamente, no sé dónde está el error. Obvio que algo está mal. Y la conexión si es correcta, ya que puedo hacer consultas con mi conexión a la BD.

Comment: Bien, ya me arroja un error. Cambié a este ciclo: for($i=0;$i<$contador1;$i++) {                    
                 $sql = ("CALL SP_Insertar_Antecedentes_Hereditarios_YFamiliares_Med_Gene('[$idlast]'[$i], 
                 '[$Id_paciente]'[$i], '[$Padeci_Hederitario_Paterno]'[$i], '[$Id_Tipo_familiar]'[$i])");
                 $result1 = mysqli_query($conexion4, $sql);                     
               }   Y, me dice lo siguiente: "Array to string conversion" justamente dónde están los campos.