# Como imprimir en pantalla una consulta a una DB mysql desde php

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente inset y me esta tirando un error no encuentro el problema, y queria consultarles a ver si uds saben como imprimir la sentencia SQL para ver que estoy enviando mal he probado con echo $statement y con print_r, pero nada...

```
id_v = "";
$cantidad =  $_POST['cantidad'];
$producto = $_POST['descripcion'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$subtotal= ($precio * $cantidad);
//   id id_v    cant    descripcion subtotal    usuario     
$statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO detalle_venta values(null,:id_v, :cant,:producto,:precio,:usuario)");  
$statement ->execute(array( 
    ':id_v'=> $id_v,  
        ':cant'=> $cantidad,
        ':producto'=> $producto,
    ':precio'=> $subtotal,
    ':usuario'=> $usuario
        )); 
   // print_r($statement); exit();  
   // echo $statement; exit();
    echo "Prepare failed: (". $conexion->error.") ".$conexion->error."<br>";
```

Comment: Buenas, para saber qué puede ser lo que pueda estar ocasionando el error puedes hacer uso de la propiedad `error` de statement, es decir si $statement devuelve `false` significará que la sentencia ha fallado y para acceder al error en específico puedes poner "$statement->error" que devolverá el error como tal.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo saber en PHP por que mi consulta SQL falla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297987/c%c3%b3mo-saber-en-php-por-que-mi-consulta-sql-falla)

Comment: Hola Ssnov, muchas gracias por tu tiempo, he probado como indicas, pero simplemente me dice que hay un error ("Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool"), pero no me envia la sentencia como para ver cual es el error, o si hay algun valor en null, en fin. Igualmente muchas gracias!

Comment: @FranciscoHaro, eso quiere decir que el `prepare` esta fallando. Debes tener un error de sintaxis. Revisar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297988/16597) donde habla de `PDO` y sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Gracias Marcos, estoy re comenzando en php y tenia algunos conceptos olvidados... lo resolvi de manera procedimental

Comment: ¿Para quién es el `null` en tu lista de valores: `null,:id_v, :cant,:producto,:precio,:usuario`? ¿No será para la columna id, a la cual le pasas también el marcador `:id_v`? Los `INSERT` implícitos son una mala práctica, nadie más que el que escribió la consulta los entiende, no se tiene ni idea de cuántas columnas tiene esa tabla. Además, si un día agregas una nueva columna a esa tabla los INSERT implícitos pasarán a ser código erróneo en la aplicación. Considera poner siempre todas las columnas explícitamente. En cuanto al manejo de errores, puedes ponerlo todo en bloque `try ... catch...`